# React Router - Stay at the same page after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, refresh, router

I'm learning React. I have page with 4 subpages and i use React Router to go through those pages. Everything works fine except for reloading page. When i go from page "home" to "about" or other it's ok, but when i refresh page then it render again page "about" for a second and then it change page to home (home is default/first page).I want it to stay at that page which is currently rendered, not go back to home after every refresh.
There is my code in index.js file where i render whole app and use router:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router path="/" history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/home" component={App}> 
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/allhotels" component={AllHotels}/>
            <Route path="/addhotel" component={AddHotel} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
```

In "App" i have Navigation and there i render rest of conent from Home, AllHotels etc.

There is code from App.jsx

```
class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div className="app-comp">
            <Navigation />
            <div> {this.props.children}</div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I also attach gif which shows my problem.

https://gifyu.com/image/boMp

In backend i use Firebase if it's important.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that firebase does not interfares with the client side routes :P

You can use Index routes to achieve this.

You have your navigation i.e the layout of all pages in your app component so make it the root route.

Then you want your home route to be your default route so make it your Index route.

You need to import IndexRoute from react-router package (from which you import Route).

Add this-

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
```

and then make your routes like below.

Use this-

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}> 
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/allhotels" component={AllHotels}/>
            <Route path="/addhotel" component={AddHotel} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: I saw this solution in the internet but it not helps also. Acctualy it doesn't change anything. It works the same as my previous code.

Comment: have you changed your routes with these? I am sure they will work. Please make sure you copy entire. I have removed path from your router component also which was causing this error.

Comment: Yes, I've coppied entire snippet and paste it instead my code. But it not helps :(

Comment: Wait let me see how can I share my code with you. Will it be any benefit if I share example from my own app?

Comment: Of course it will help me when i see working solution, because for now i do what You said but really it not works. Maybe it's issue not from that file? Or just i have older version of React Router?

Comment: What version it is? v2 or v4

Comment: I use version 3.0.1. 
Ok but when i do some changes or refresh page (but actually it's obvious) it also back to home from other pages like in my application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148487/discussion-between-arshmeet-and-skylin-r).

Answer (score 5):

I found the reason of my problem. I use also Firebase in my project and it causes the problem. 
Thanks guys for help.

EDIT ======================================================================

Mabye I will write how I've fixed my problem and what was the reason of it.
So i was checking if user is logged in or not in auth method. And there if user was authorized I was pushing `/` to browserHistory.
It was mistake because every refresh method was executing and then also redirection was called as well.
Solution is just to check if during executing auth method I'm on Signin page or not. If it is Signin page then I'm pushing `/` to browserHistory but if not then just don't push anything.

```
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
     if (user) {
        let currentPathname = browserHistory.getCurrentLocation().pathname;
        if( currentPathname === "/" || currentPathname === "/signin"){
          browserHistory.push('/');
        }
        const { email } = user;
        store.dispatch(logUser(email));
     }
     else {
        browserHistory.replace('/signin');
     }
    })
```

I know that it's not pretty solution but it works and it was only home project which was created to learn react. (btw this project is using old react router 3.0 so probalby now using browserHistory is deprecated)

Comment: ... and what was the problem/solution ?

Comment: @Wingjam it was caused by my auth method where after checking user I was pushing '/' to browserHistory :P so with every app refresh I was checking if user is authorized and if he was then moved him to home directory ('/').

Answer (score 1):

it's a Server-side vs Client-side issue
check the following thread, it might give you some insights.. [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

Answer (score 1):

Below example you can refer for :

- React Router Navigation
- Browser Refresh Issue.
- Browser Back Button Issue.

Please make sure you have installed `react-router-dom`

If not installed. Use this command to install `npm i react-router-dom`

***index.js***

```
   import React from "react";
   import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
   import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

   import Page1 from "./Page1";
   import Page2 from "./Page2";

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>,
      rootElement
    );
```

***Page1.js***

```
   import React from "react";
   import {Link } from "react-router-dom";

    function Page1() {

        return (
          <div>
            <p>
              This is the first page.
              <br />
              Click on the button below.
            </p>
            <Link to="/page2"><button>
              Go to Page 2 
            </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        );

    }

    export default Page1;
```

***Page2.js***

```
   import React from "react";

   function Page2() {

        return (
          <div>
            <p>This is the second page.</p>
          </div>
        );

    }

    export default Page2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add into your `webpack.config.js` this option

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
},
```

Comment: It not helped :(

Comment: Have you modified `output.publicPath` in your Webpack configuration?

Comment: I have edited webpack js not configuration file, because i cant find it. Should i create it? I can't also find something like output public path.
I haven't add webpack by myself, it was added automatically when I was creating project.

Comment: The `webpack.config.js` is at the root of the project.

Comment: I've checked and in node modules i have folder webpack, but i don't have installed webpack because now i've install it. Unfortunately don't have  webpack.config.js still. I've installed webpack from https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack

Comment: How do you run project? What do you server use?

Comment: I use node, and i start project by npm start. I start creating app from here https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: @SkylinR you might have to eject your webpack config `npm run eject` or `yarn run eject` or `npx react-scripts eject`

Answer (score 0):

Route tag returns the first matching component.
I think you have interchanged the paths of home and app component.

try this.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router path="/" history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}> 
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/allhotels" component={AllHotels}/>
            <Route path="/addhotel" component={AddHotel} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: It's not workign now default render only App without any content and then Home button render Home content etc. But there is still the same problem.