# How to know which component was being rendered before the page was refreshed without using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically what I want to do is when page refreshes I want the same component to be rendered that was rendered when the page was refreshed. How do I get the name of the component that was being rendered.**Also I have not used react-router anywhere in my project. Is it possible to do what I am asking without react-router?**

I have used onbeforeunload event to detect page refresh. Now what should I do in its function to render the same component?
This code is in my app.js component's componentDidMount()

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { e.preventDefault()
  return console.log('Hello123')
};
```

This is logging Hello123 in the console.The only problem is to get the name of the last rendered component. Is there any way to make the app remember the name of last rendered component and after refresh check if there a name and render that component if there is  one.

for example suppose I am rendering a component called TravellerList and on a button click I am rendering the component called AddTraveller. Now how do I get the name of the component that is being rendered and store it in a variable **Without using react-router** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router - Stay at the same page after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943920/react-router-stay-at-the-same-page-after-refresh)

Comment: You could consider using localStorage to set the latest view component being loaded. If you are using React router, then you can check for this localStorage item and force a certain route to be loaded.

Comment: Yes I saw that question but here what I want to do is to remember the name of last rendered component and store it in a variable without using react-router. Also I have not used react-router anywhere in my project

Comment: @Winston Yes that is the problem I have not used react-router anywhere in my project, that is why asking if there is way around for this to be done without using react-router

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use local-storage or Cookie if you want to get values after page refresh because after page refresh all the objects in JavaScript will be refreshed. what you can do is create a local-storage or cookie object like in the Highest level component.

```
var myObj = {
        component1Rendered:false,
        component2Rendered:false,
        component3Rendered:false,
        component4Rendered:false

    };
```

Then set value to that object when u Render some Component
As an Example:
In Component1
inside componentDidMount in all components update that object as they rendered.

```
        componentDidMount() {
        var myObj = {
            component1Rendered:true,
            component2Rendered:false,
            component3Rendered:false,
            component4Rendered:false

        };

            localStorage.setItem('storeObj', JSON.stringify(myObj));
        // please not that this is a sample set statement in your scenario update only the specific value of that object in local-storage 
       }
```

After Page Refresh happens check the local-storage object find the components that have rendered previously using your function,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { e.preventDefault()
  return console.log('Hello123')
 storeObj = localStorage.getItem('storeObj');
// Filter storeObj and get the rendered components
};
```

Comment: Yes this can be useful

Comment: Ok..did u try that?

Comment: There is a new problem now. See I have App component that renders TravellerList component that renders AddTraveller component inside a dialogbox on a button click. Now I am in the AddTraveller before I refreshed the page which I stored and retrieved from the localstorage somehow. Now how do I display AddTraveller component inside the dialog box like it is displayed ON button click?

Comment: you have to add another parameter to local-storage like dialogBoxOn=false and when u click on the button create a separate method to set it true. When the refresh happen check in the TravellerList(inside componentDidMount)  that dialogbox value and if it is true open the dialog-box from the code side.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one

```
  componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onBeforeUnload);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onBeforeUnload);

  }
  onBeforeUnload = (e) => {
    const msg = 'Do you want to leave this site?\n\nChanges you made may not be saved.';
    e.returnValue = msg;
    return msg;
  }
```

you need react-router. check this [React Router - Stay at the same page after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943920/react-router-stay-at-the-same-page-after-refresh)

Comment: The main purpose is to render the same page even after the page is refreshed. Is that possible?

Comment: i don't get it. do you want a redirect?

Comment: I have edited the question maybe now it is more clear

Comment: What I want is let the user refresh the page but it should render the same component as it was when the user refreshed the page when it is loaded again.

Comment: are you using react-router?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943920/react-router-stay-at-the-same-page-after-refresh

Comment: No I am not using react-router I am just using simple variables and changing their values to show different components. Is there any way to do this without router